# Different Application, different outputs

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, audio-output

I'd like to send Pandora One to the Speakers, and Chrome (or anything else besides Pandora) to the Headphone jack (although different combinations might exist).

A quick look shows two main options:

- Check the application options - Some applications let you choose a desired output.
- Check the Driver/Sound Card Application.

I seem to be choosing two options that don't have "Application Option" (Chrome and Pandora One). I'm using on-board dell audio and I don't seem to have a control panel other than the included windows one.

Are there any other options available? Are there any software solutions or windows options that I missing?

Comment: Usually that depends on the application itself, for example, Skype lets you choose different aduio outputs while Chrome uses default one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been seeing. Either application option or driver manager option. I'm wondering if there is anything for corner cases? Pandora and Chrome both default to... default. What if I want to split them? Minor update to question to reflect this.

Comment: It seems to be options with the driver that give certain applications the option of controlling the speakers; here is an image of my computer that shows this - http://imgur.com/8E5JaGc

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove I have those options as well. The issue is those options are sound level per application, and on/off per application. Not destination per application. Pandora to speakers, Chrome to headset, WMP to bluetooth, etc

Comment: @WernerCD Do you have the Realtek (if this is your audio driver) audio manager installed?

Comment: I didn't see it as an option on Dells website.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't come with it on Dells website @WerverCD ; here is the realtek drivers from their website. Give that a install and you should be able to find the manager. http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Trying that now - I had seen that page and thought it was just codecs (not the manager). Although I was more thinking of an option that precludes drivers and application support, in my work environment I just need something that works.

Comment: @WernerCD understandable. Let me know how that goes, you might have to download the last option (if any of the others do not include this).

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove I've done two downloads (8x64 and 3DS) and no dice. No audio manager. All the options are "driver only".

Comment: under recording in your sound options do you see something that says "stereo mix"?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Just Microphone and Line-In

Comment: I would just search for an audio manager for the certain driver you have, otherwise I'm thinking you might need a sound card.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application known as "Virtual Audio Cable" that might allow you to achieve the desired goal.

It allows the creation of virtual input and output interfaces which can then be mapped to physical audio inputs and outputs on the computer.

Unfortunately, some sound card drivers are so designed that if you were to plug a set of headphones into the output jack, the speakers are then bypassed/disabled. If that is the case, then your only recourse would be to have an additional soundsystem attached via HDMI, or via USB sound card, allowing you to choose between the headphones on the computer or the speakers on the external device.